# Fixing colors when plot charts using python - plotly

Tags: python, colors, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I'm looking for some fix for this issue here.

I'm trying to set some Charts, but all colors are the same in bars, but it's right at legend.

```
df_carteira = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

carteira_linha = df_carteira['Status'] == 'approved'
carteira_coluna = ['nome_carteira', 'Valor']
df_carteira = df_carteira.loc[carteira_linha, carteira_coluna]

fig = px.bar(df_carteira, x=df_carteira['nome_carteira'], y=df_carteira['Valor'], color=df_carteira['nome_carteira'])

fig.update_layout({
'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
})

fig.show()
```

Do you guys know how to fix this kind of issue?

Chat displayed:

[printed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpZ9R.png)

Comment: Please share a sample of your data in order to make a reproducible code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try instead of `color = df['nome_carteira']` pass a range of colors like eg color = ['red', 'green', 'yellow'] always equal to the number of attributes on your list `df['nome_carteira']` . You can also use seaborn, in which it already has a defined color range.

Source:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Exemple finaly:

```py
px.bar(
    df_carteira,
    x=df_carteira['nome_carteira'],
    y=df_carteira['Valor'], 
    color=['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'dark', 'blue']
)
```